# MySQL gives error on where clause

Tags: mysql

I'm following a tutorial for mysql and it gives me an error but not him

```
UPDATE members SET birthday '2002-01-01'
WHERE `member_id` = 2
```

I get

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2002-01-01' WHERE `member_id` = 2' at line 1

Comment: `UPDATE members SET birthday = '2002-01-01' WHERE member_id = 2` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `=` sign in your set.Try this:-

```
UPDATE members SET birthday = '2002-01-01' WHERE member_id = 2
```